# Hiding the column filer for the particular column in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any possibility to skip the column filtering for the particular column in JQGrid?  i don't want a filtering option for some columns. Or is there any option to hide the column filtering for the particular columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need just add `search: false` property (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options)) to the column definition in `colModel` for which you don't want make filtering.